# Show data in Textboxes from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Is there anything wrong with my code? It is not showing data in textboxes. The same funtion is working for another table in database but not for this one.

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        String query = "Select FROM Student WHERE Std_ID = '" + metroTextBox1.Text + "'";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    // metroTextBox1.Text = (read["ID"].ToString());
                    metroTextBox2.Text = (read["Name"].ToString());
                    metroTextBox3.Text = (read["F_Name"].ToString());
                    metroTextBox4.Text = (read["Std_Age"].ToString());
                    metroTextBox5.Text = (read["Address"].ToString());
                    metroTextBox6.Text = (read["Program"].ToString());
                    metroComboBox1.Text = (read["Course"].ToString());

                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Select * from ...`?

Comment: Select from Student. Student is the table name. I have made the connection string global so that i can access it in any function.

Comment: check the answer by damith

Comment: As stated, you're missing `*`. But a big issue is that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I did put * but still not working. Right now i am not giving attention to security as i am not developing a complete application. It's just my class assignment and i am stuck here.

Comment: Do you get an error ??... and probably `metroTextBox1.Text` has no value and that's why nothing shows in your textboxes

Comment: Nope not getting any error i enter id in metrotextbox1 and it shows nothing.

Answer (score 2):

you need to **give column names in the select** statement or **select ***

for example :

```
 String query = "Select * from Student WHERE Std_ID = '" + metroTextBox1.Text + "'";
```

Not related to Question: you can change the while loop to if condition if you have one record for given id. even there are many records for given id you will see the last record data only because of the while loop will overwrite the textboxes in every record.

Update :

> There isn't anything wrong with Syntax because the same syntax is
>   working for modifying teacher funtion.

No, this is incorrect, remove the try catch in your code then you will see the exception of `syntax error`

Comment: Nope i am trying to enter ID in textbox and when i will click on the search button then that button will show the all the name of the student with that specific ID in their relative textboxes.

Comment: that's ok, but you need to have correct sql syntax for that.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with Syntax because the same syntax is working for modifying teacher funtion. I just copied the same code in this function but here it is not working. I have checked all the relative textboxes and checked the query again but of no use.